ROS2 Iron: Action Servers Become Unresponsive After Modifying Collision Checking
I'm working on a ROS2 Iron project and have encountered a perplexing issue with my action servers. I've implemented collision checking modification without using MoveIt Task Constructor (which isn't available for Iron). The core functionality works, but I'm facing a critical problem:
The Issue:
After executing a collision checking modification, ALL action servers in my main node become unresponsive. Here's what I've observed:

The modify_collision_checking function executes successfully and completes.
I receive a success message: [INFO] Completed modify_collision_checking: test_box, ['r1_gripper'], True, telling me the funciton executed all the way.
After this, no action servers in the main node respond to messages.

What I've Tried:

Other action servers work fine when used independently.
If I replace the content of modify_collision_checking with pass, it works repeatedly without issues.

The Code:
Here's a simplified version of my CollisionObjectHandler class:
class CollisionObjectHandler:
   def __init__(self, node: Node):
       self.node = node

   def modify_collision_checking(
       self, object_id: str, target_names: list, allow: bool
   ):
       try:
           get_planning_scene = self.node.get_planning_scene
           while not get_planning_scene.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
               self.node.logger.info(
                   "get_planning_scene service not available, waiting..."
               )


           req = GetPlanningScene.Request()
           req.components.components = PlanningSceneComponents.ALLOWED_COLLISION_MATRIX


           future = get_planning_scene.call_async(req)
           rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self.node, future)
           response = future.result()


           if response is None:
               self.node.logger.error("Failed to get current planning scene")
               return


           current_scene = response.scene


           if current_scene.allowed_collision_matrix.entry_names:
               acm = current_scene.allowed_collision_matrix
           else:
               acm = AllowedCollisionMatrix()


           self.node.logger.debug(f"Current ACM entries: {acm.entry_names}")


           for name in [object_id] + target_names:
               if name not in acm.entry_names:
                   acm.entry_names.append(name)
                   new_entry = AllowedCollisionEntry()
                   new_entry.enabled = [False] * len(acm.entry_names)
                   acm.entry_values.append(new_entry)


           for entry in acm.entry_values:
               while len(entry.enabled) < len(acm.entry_names):
                   entry.enabled.append(False)


           obj_index = acm.entry_names.index(object_id)
           for target_name in target_names:
               target_index = acm.entry_names.index(target_name)
               acm.entry_values[obj_index].enabled[target_index] = allow
               acm.entry_values[target_index].enabled[obj_index] = allow
               self.node.logger.debug(
                   f"Modified collision between {object_id} and {target_name}: {allow}"
               )


           planning_scene_msg = PlanningScene()
           planning_scene_msg.is_diff = True
           planning_scene_msg.allowed_collision_matrix = acm


           self.node.scene_pub.publish(planning_scene_msg)


           action = "Allowed" if allow else "Disallowed"
           self.node.logger.debug(
               f"{action} collisions between {object_id} and {target_names}"
           )


           self.node.logger.debug("Updated ACM:")
           for i, entry_name in enumerate(acm.entry_names):
               self.node.logger.debug(f"{entry_name}: {acm.entry_values[i].enabled}")


       except Exception as e:
           self.node.logger.error(f"Error modifying collision checking: {str(e)}")


       self.node.logger.info(
           f"Completed modify_collision_checking: {object_id}, {target_names}, {allow}"
       )





   def change_object_collision_callback(self, goal_handle):
       self.node.logger.info(
           f"Received new change_object_collision request: {goal_handle.request}"
       )
       object_id = goal_handle.request.object_id
       allow_collision = goal_handle.request.allow
       gripper_name = "r1_gripper"


       if allow_collision:
           self.modify_collision_checking(object_id, [gripper_name], True)
       else:
           self.modify_collision_checking(object_id, [gripper_name], False)

       success = True
       message = f"{'Allowed' if allow_collision else 'Disallowed'} collisions between {object_id} and gripper"
       goal_handle.succeed()
       return ChangeObjectCollision.Result(success=success, message=message)

And I'm setting up the action server like this in my main node (which imports CollisionObjectHandler:
class PlanningAndSceneManagerServer(Node):
    """
    A ROS2 node for managing the scene, including mesh acquisition and object placement.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("scene_manager_server")
        self.collision_object_handler = CollisionObjectHandler(self)
        self.scene_pub = self.create_publisher(
            PlanningScene, "/planning_scene", qos_profile
        )
        self.get_planning_scene = self.create_client(
            GetPlanningScene, "/get_planning_scene"
        )

        self._change_collision_server = ActionServer(
            self,
            ChangeObjectCollision,
            "change_object_collision",
            self
        self._change_attachment_server = ActionServer(
            self,...

The Question:
What could be causing all action servers to become unresponsive after modify_collision_checking executes? Is there something in this function that might be interfering with the ROS2 communication infrastructure?
Again, the function itself does not get stuck. It terminates successfully and the ActionServer sends a Success message. Only afterwards, all action servers (also these fully independent of CollistionObjectHandler) of the main script no longer receive.
Any insights or suggestions for debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to alternative approaches or workarounds if necessary.

Have you considered using a ReentrantCallbackGroup and a MultiThreadedExecutor? This approach can help prevent blocking and allow for concurrent execution of callbacks. Here's how you might modify your code:

In your PlanningAndSceneManagerServer class:

from rclpy.callback_groups import ReentrantCallbackGroup

class PlanningAndSceneManagerServer(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        # ... (existing code)
        self.callback_group = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        self._change_collision_server = ActionServer(
            self,
            ChangeObjectCollision,
            "change_object_collision",
            self.collision_object_handler.change_object_collision_callback,
            callback_group=self.callback_group
        )


Modify your main function to use a MultiThreadedExecutor:

from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    scene_manager = PlanningAndSceneManagerServer()
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(scene_manager)
    scene_manager.get_logger().info("PlanningAndSceneManagerServer is running")
    try:
        executor.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        scene_manager.get_logger().info("Shutting down PlanningAndSceneManagerServer")
        scene_manager.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()


Make your change_object_collision_callback method asynchronous:

class CollisionObjectHandler:
    async def change_object_collision_callback(self, goal_handle):
        # ... (existing code)
        if not skip_activation:
            if allow_collision:
                await self.deactivate_collision_checking_with_gripper(object_id)
            else:
                await self.activate_collision_checking_with_gripper(object_id)
        # ... (rest of the method)

This setup should allow for better concurrency and prevent the action servers from becoming unresponsive. Give it a try and let us know if it helps!

Thank you for the detailed suggestion! Unfortunately, I've already tested this approach, and it doesn't solve the issue. The behavior remains the same: all action servers become unresponsive after modify_collision_checking is called once.
The function completes successfully, but afterwards, all action servers stop receiving messages.
I'm wondering if there's a more fundamental issue with how the collision checking modification interacts with ROS2. Do you have any other debugging strategies we could try? I'm at a loss and would appreciate any further insights.
